# Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work

Tags: ffmpeg, python

I'm trying to have a Python Script run using FFMPEG, however even though FFMPEG is installed on my Mac OS system, I get this message when running the module through IDLE:

`Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work`

The python script is calling on the following:

```
import json, os, shutil, random, subprocess
from PIL import Image
from pydub import AudioSegment
import ffmpeg
```

Any idea of what I could do to make this work? (I'm not very good at any programming language, just trying to solve the problem so I can use the script.) Thanks!

Comment: Try the solution form [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258377/4926757). If it's not working, Google search: *Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work pydub*

Comment: I have tried this for sure. My current tryout is:  import json, os, shutil, random, subprocess
from PIL import Image
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1/bin/ffmpeg'
import ffmpeg - but this is not working

Comment: Did you install `python-ffmpeg` or a similar ffmpeg library for python via `pip`?